# Is there a shortcut in Ruby for if defined?(var) && var == x?

Tags: ruby

Is there a shortcut in Ruby for:

```
if defined?(var) && var == x
  # do something
else
  # do something
end
```

like `defined_and_equal(var, x)`?

Comment: It's very unusual to see `defined?` used within Ruby, it's quite tricky to have *sometimes* defined variables within a scope, so I doubt this will ever end up as some kind of shorthand. Making a macro method to do this is self-defeating, too, as it obscures what's actually happening. When I see things like this, it's almost always from someone who's trying to force Ruby to behave like another programming language.

Comment: @tadman: yeah, like PHP :)

Comment: What's wrong with just `if var == x`?

Comment: @GetSet It raises an error is `var` is not defined.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, there isn't that shortcut.

Answer (score 5):

```
defined_and_equal(var, x)
defined?(var) && var == x
|    |    |    |    |    |
```

Your "shortcut" has the same length. So I really don't see why you would prefer it. And no, I don't know if such method exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if `x` is not a falesy value.

```
if (var ||= nil) == x
  # do something
else
  # do something
end
```

Comment: Your code will define `var` and assign `nil` to it if it's not defined while `defined?(var)` won't. Much easier to insert `var = nil` before code in question.